# Shell script on startup to click specific location?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to open chromium to a specific webpage and click a full screen button. I currently have three scripts TV_Setup.sh, Start_Browser.sh, and Full_Screen.

TV_Setup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Starts both scripts separate to remove open thread issue
home/pi/Full_Screen.sh & home/pi/Start_Browser.sh
```

Start_Browser.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Running the broswer on the main desktop
sudo -u pi chromium-browser http://TestPage.com
```

Full_Screen.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Wait a few seconds to make sure the browser starts successfully
sleep 10s;
# Wait a few seconds confirm full screen
DISPLAY=:0.0 XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority /usr/bin/xte 'mousemove 40 490' 'm$
# To check resolution
# fbset -s
```

It works when testing from the command prompt, but on reboots it only opens the webpage. I've tried to also schedule Full_Screen.sh with CronTab, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `selenium` for this. It makes life so much easier.

Comment: `but on reboots it only opens the webpage` how do you run the script on reboot? The easiest it to add it to your startup with the Xserver or window manager or whatevery you have there (you didn't specify), not with system startup.

Comment: Sorry about that I should have clarified. I've modified "sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart" to add "@sh /home/pi/Start_Browser_v3.0.sh" to the end of the script.